# Algorithm to compute monomial coefficients from Vieta's Formulas

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, algorithms, combinations

Let's say I know the $N$ roots $\boldsymbol r$ of a polynomial $p_N(x)$ and I want to compute the coefficients $\boldsymbol \alpha $ of the representation in monomials, i.e.,
$$p_N(x) = \sum_{j=0}^N \alpha_j x^j. $$

[Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas) give an readily understood way of how to do this, but I struggle with the (efficient) implementation. Throughout the computation of the $\alpha_j$, the roots are combined in $2^N -1$ different ways. To see this, consider the power set of $\{1, \dots, N \}$ which has $2^N$ elements. The products $$ \prod_{i \in S \subset\{1, \dots, N \}} r_i$$ are then summed up for subsets $S$ of same cardinality $n>0$ to give the $\alpha_{N-n}$ coefficient.

I was wondering whether someone sees an alternative way of computing the sums of products than enumerating the whole powerset (which consumes drastic amounts of memory just for storing them for $N \sim \mathcal{O}(50)$) and then summing the products of the subsets with same cardinality.

Comment: See [What is the Computational Complexity of the Elementary Symmetric Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116109/what-is-the-computational-complexity-of-the-elementary-symmetric-polynomials) and the linked [What is the most efficient algorithm to compute polynomial coefficients from its roots?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116643/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-compute-polynomial-coefficients-from-its).

Comment: I went [with this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594384/find-the-coefficients-of-the-polynomial-given-its-roots)